# First epoch slot and stability window

Tags: stake-pool, query

I am building a Cron job to check leader-slots and during testing/learning phase I saw that the command will not start if the slot isn't greater than first slot of the epoch + stability window slots amount or 1.5 days.

Reading around the web I found out that stability window could be edited by the protocol in some cases (please correct me if I am wrong), and so my question is:

Is there a way to query the first block of the epoch and the current stability window? This way I can check those parameters first and then run leadership-schedule command.
Or can you advise other ways to run the leadership-schedule command with a cronjob and being sure that it will run?

Thanks for your time. Have a great day.

**EDIT:**
what I am currently doing is reading gLiveView code and understanding it.

I found out that there is a function called getEpochStart and I could use it with epoch % of completion to find out when run the job, this way I wouldn't need the Stability window slot amount.

From what I understood, the math that I would need to do is:

```
timestamp = byron_genesis_start_sec(1563999616) + ((epoch_no(197) * BYRON_EPOCH_LENGTH(21600) * BYRON_SLOT_LENGTH(20000)) / 1000)
```

By doing the math, I got that epoch 197 of Testnet started on timestamp: 1649103616 which sounds odd to me cause it would be at 08:20PM UTC and from what I know, epoch starts at 09:45PM UTC.

Am I missing something?

**Edit2:**
Here's the script that I built after the answer was given to me.
I am not an expert on BASH but I does the work, feel free to contact me if you need help with it or have any improvement/suggestions.
[Link to the script](https://github.com/Techs2Help/leaderScheduleCheck_cron)

Comment: Your calc looks ok. Testnet started epoch 0 at 2019/07/24 20:20:16 according to https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/browse-epochs?page=0&perPage=10
Mainnet is 2017/09/23 21:44:51

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks so much.

I'll upload the script once finished in case someone needs it :-)

Also if you add your comment to your answer I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `next` epoch once the current epoch is 70+% (3.5 days) through, eg:

`cardano-cli query leadership-schedule --mainnet ...... --next`

You can then:

1. Use cron and date checking to run this query every 5 days to coincide with being say 75% through the current epoch, or
2. Check chain/epoch details to determine % through the current epoch and then run the query.

**Edit** - Added details from comment:

Your calc looks ok.

Testnet started epoch 0 at 2019/07/24 20:20:16 UTC according to https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/browse-epochs.html?page=0&perPage=10

Mainnet started at 2017/09/23 21:44:51 UTC